# Move existing subview above another subview

Tags: swift

How can I move an already inserted subview just above another subview? I could do

```
subview1.removeFromSuperview()
view.insertSubview(subview1, aboveSubview: subview2)
```

but there must be a better way.

Comment: How many subview do you have? Else, maybe combining `sendSubviewToBack()`, `bringSubviewToFront()`, `exchangeSubview(at:, withSubviewAt:)`... and with `subviews` which should get you the order of them.

Comment: @Larme: Potentially in the hundreds. The user can create new subviews by pressing various buttons and I need to move some of them above others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can cut your code by a half. You don't remove `subview1` manually from its superview. It will be removed by `insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)`. **Note**: This in case `subview1` superview is different then `subview2` superview. Hope it helps.

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622570-insertsubview)

Comment: Thanks! In my case the superview of subview1 and subview2 is the same, but it works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can rearrange your subviews using this method, other than those two methods to my knowledge there isn't a better or more elegant way.

```
bringSubviewToFront(_:)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622541-bringsubviewtofront